# Diagonalisability of Self-Adjoint Operators for Non-Symmetric Metrics

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, bilinear-form, adjoint-operators

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $(\cdot,\cdot)$ a non-degenerate bilinear form. When $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is symmetric, every self-adjoint operator on $V$ is diagonalisable. What happens when $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is not necessarily symmetric?

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the diagonalizability of self-adjoint operators in symmetric bilinear forms? I'm having a problem with that, so I want to get all the terms right.

Answer (score 1):

The inner product over complex numbers, for example, is not symmetric, although it has the conjugate symmetry axiom: $\langle x,y\rangle=\overline{\langle y,x\rangle}$. That didn't prevent people to prove the diagonalisability of self-adjoint operators. Actually, self-adjoint operators are only defined for such inner-products.